# If I make an @user comment, then delete it, does the user still get notified?

Tags: discussion, comment, comment-replies

Sometimes I write an @user comment, then delete it.  For example, it might need significant editing, or I might subsequently think it's not important enough to leave.

> **Question**: If I make an @user comment, then delete it, does the user still get notified?

I'm just worried it would be annoying.

And for extra credit (depending on the answer to the first question):

> **Question**: If I make several @user comment, then delete them all, does the user get notified each time?

E.g. if I edit multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

As you make an @user comment, the user will be notified.

As you delete the @user comment, the notification will be purged from the user's inbox.

But as with all things software/on the internet, there is a small delay (not to mention the human delay). This causes a race condition that it is technically possible for a user to open up his inbox, read the first few words of your comment, click on the link, only to find out that the comment doesn't exist.

Comment: Corollary: if the user is online at the time and watching his inbox, you _may_ annoy him by doing that. If the user is offline for a while, then he won't notice what you did.

Comment: Thanks!  That clears it up.

Comment: What happens if I change @user to @user2? Will both be notified?

Comment: haha I get the warning that only one user will be notified, although none of them exists. $\color{red}{\text{(bug)}}$

Comment: related to the $\color{red}{\text{(bug)}}$: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/7149/19341

Comment: related to my first question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/7150/19341

Comment: @draks: I answered in your other thread.