# Using @'s in a comment triggers the "One additional @user" box after editing, even though the users don't exist.

Tags: bug, comment, comment-replies

In this [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7145/if-i-make-an-user-comment-then-delete-it-does-the-user-still-get-notified#comment26321_7147), I addressed a question that has two @'s in there, without the intention to ping someone.

It was no problem to write the comment having two @'s,  but after an edit it showed:

[image]

even though the user didn' exist. At least in the context of the answer and their comments.

Comment: I removed the minor bug tag: reading the official FAQ on how comment replies work http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work my impression is that my interpretation of the FAQ post describes a behaviour different from what you saw. Either the (semi)official doc should be clarified or the bug fixed.

Comment: @WillieWong ok...@toberemoved. strange, I can remove the second @ here without a problem, but when I tried to edit to _at_here the box appears. It's a bug...maybe you play around a little yourself!