# What happens if I change @user to @user2? Will both be notified?

Tags: support, comment-replies

This also came up in this [post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7147/19341).

> What happens if I change @user to @user2 in a comment by an edit? Will both be notified?

The system seems to have at least a trigger, since [using @'s in a comment triggers the “One additional @user” box **after** editing, even though the user don't exist.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7149/19341)

Comment: Of course, if the strings were indeed $\text{@}$user and $\text{@}$user2, the edit would have no effect at all: only the first three symbols are used to match comments to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See bullet point (9) in the further details section of [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

In particular

> In the new system, edits to comments do not reflect in your global inbox. Edits to comments still reflect in the "responses" report on your profile page. There's still no actual pointing out of this fact, and unless you frequent your own profile page as a means of keeping up to date, it is possible to miss the notice.

So the system will notify the user, just not in a very noticeable way.

Comment: interesting thanks. So if forgot to add @ToBePinged in the first revision of my comment, he/she/it won't get the usual notification, right?

Comment: Define "usual notification". If you mean "little red circled number on the global inbox on the top left of every page" then you are right.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. $\phantom{space}$